# No money deducted from Recurring Payment Profile on Sandbox

Tags: paypal

I am creating recurring profiles on sandbox. However, these profiles are not charged and I am not getting payments from these profiles. Also, I receive only on IPN (recurring profile created) and nothing more.

Bellow is request to create profile

```
METHOD=CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile&
VERSION=86&
PWD=XXXXXXXX&
USER=user_name_here&
SIGNATURE=signature&
PROFILESTARTDATE=2014-11-18T18%3A19%3A10Z&
DESC=XXX&
BILLINGPERIOD=Day&
BILLINGFREQUENCY=1&
TOTALBILLINGCYCLES=5&
AMT=12.00&
CURRENCYCODE=PLN&
COUNTRYCODE=PL&
MAXFAILEDPAYMENTS=3&
TOKEN=EC-6JU772384N300610X&
PAYERID=WZFP8V87D4AUU&
PROFILEREFERENCE=16
```

And IPN for created profile. Strange: that next_payment_date is earlier than time_created. On the other hand, time_created is correct

```
'payment_cycle' => 'Daily'
'txn_type' => 'recurring_payment_profile_created'
'last_name' => 'Buyer'
'next_payment_date' => '02:00:00 Nov 18, 2014 PST'
'residence_country' => 'PL'
'initial_payment_amount' => '0.00'
'rp_invoice_id' => '16'
'currency_code' => 'PLN'
'time_created' => '10:16:54 Nov 18, 2014 PST'
'verify_sign' => 'AJHdwbpCu.We0o1oi9ns0.O4SzOKAbKLMWyC6m3zKtaUUxuNXSzYhvGv'
'period_type' => ' Regular'
'payer_status' => 'verified'
'test_ipn' => '1'
'tax' => '0.00'
'payer_email' => 'some@mail.pl'
'first_name' => 'Test'
'receiver_email' => 'other@mail.pl'
'payer_id' => 'WZFP8V87D4AUU'
'product_type' => '1'
'shipping' => '0.00'
'amount_per_cycle' => '12.00'
'profile_status' => 'Active'
'charset' => 'windows-1252'
'notify_version' => '3.8'
'amount' => '12.00'
'outstanding_balance' => '0.00'
'recurring_payment_id' => 'I-139NJJPKCLHJ'
'product_name' => 'XXX'
'ipn_track_id' => '81472ff322c3d'
```

Answer (score 0):

From your sandbox transaction history, is this transaction marked as 'Created' or 'Completed'? If it is 'Created', which means the recurring did not occur. The reason might be that your starting date is not good. Try to set your starting date like 1 hour after the creation time